# Why ssh keep asking passphrase while cloning project from github?

Tags: terminal, ssh-keys, wsl-2, fish

So I setup ssh key on my Ubuntu terminal(WSL2) using fish shell.
I installed [fish_ssh_agent](https://github.com/ivakyb/fish_ssh_agent), and it worked I am not entering passphrase every time I push some changes in my remote project, I am doing it only once. so ssh-agent is enabled, but when I am trying to clone any project on my PC, ssh is asking me passphrase every time.
Is this normal or need additional setup, to enter it once and after clone projects without passphrase,like I am doing with git push ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by entering this commands in config files in Ubuntu terminal,where I am using fish shell and in Git Bash too:

For fish:

```
nano ~/.config/fish/config.fish
eval (ssh-agent -c) && ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

for Git bash:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)" && ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```